# Function changes pointer arguments, but calling side can't see change

Tags: c, pointers, swap

i want to understand the nature of pointers work. And have a simple example of swap function. First is working as expected, the second fails.
I can't understand the second function swap2(). I'm swapping the addresses successfully but after the function exit the values stay the same... 
Why?

```
void swap1(int *x, int *y);
void swap2(int *x, int *y);

void startSwapExample() {
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    printf("a = %i, b = %i\n", a, b);
    swap1(&a,&b);
    printf("a = %i, b = %i\n", a, b);

    printf("\n================\n");

    int c = 10;
    int d = 20;
    printf("c = %i, d = %i\n", c, d);
    swap2(&c,&d);
    printf("c = %i, d = %i\n", c, d);
}

void swap1(int *x, int *y) {
    printf("x = %i, y = %i\n", *x, *y);
    int temp = * x;
    * x = * y;
    * y = temp;
    printf("x = %i, y = %i\n", *x, *y);
}

void swap2(int *x, int *y) {
    printf("x = %i, y = %i\n", *x, *y);
    int * temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
    printf("x = %i, y = %i\n", *x, *y);
}
```

The output of the program:

```
a = 10, b = 20
x = 10, y = 20
x = 20, y = 10
a = 20, b = 10

================
c = 10, d = 20
x = 10, y = 20
x = 20, y = 10
c = 10, d = 20

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: C does "pass by value", always, for any kind of variable, as well for pointer-variables.

Comment: In the first example you are swapping the _values_ the pointers point to, in the second one you swap the _addresses_ of local pointers (this op is not visible outside the function).

Comment: @KeineLust: Well .... "*swapping the values of the pointers*" should read "swapping the values the pointers point to", shouldn't it? And only in the 2nd case the OP just swaps their values.

Comment: @alk, you are right

Comment: In simple terms, when you pass a pointer to a function, the function receives a copy of the pointer (with its very own and very different address) The pointer still points to the correct memory location (the value of the pointer) so swapping what the pointers point to works, but if you attempt to swap the copy of the pointers themselves, that change is never seen back in the calling function.

Comment: Somebody who understands this better should edit the title.

Comment: I understand that C pass the by value. In first and second example i pass the value of pointers, its clear.

Comment: David C. Rankin  thanks, now clear. So Inside the functions I don't need to try swap the pointer variables. Because they are just copies of the originals, that's right?

Comment: Yes, at least try to write a useful title next time. "Thing X" is a hopelessly vague title for a specific question about Thing X and will just lead to people not clicking into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In swap2, you are swapping the pointer x and y, both of which only lives within the scope of the swap2 function.

When the function returns, pointer x and y no longer exist and whatever operation you did on the pointer (as opposed to the value pointed by the pointer) has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

swap2() function is not working according to your expectation, reason is below.

```
void swap2(int *x, int *y) {
        printf("x = %i, y = %i\n", *x, *y);
        int * temp = x;
        x = y;// x holding y
        y = temp;// y holding x but not in main() function, only in swap2()
        printf("x = %i, y = %i\n", *x, *y); // here you are getting expected output  but not in main() function 
    }
```

in swap2() function it's swapping but modification is not affecting in main() function  because temp as well as x & y are local pointers & and you are not de-referencing anything , so in main() it will be same.

Comment: "*because temp is local*" `x` and `y` are local as well, which is essential to the reasoning as well.

Comment: true @alk  x & y also local to swap2() functions.